# Netty server response time inconsistent

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I created a netty tcp client and server. I calculate the total response time in client. When i do a load test i see that every 8th request takes long time. What could be the reason? Any pointers on improving the performance.

```
Connecting to localhost:9065
PROCESSING TIME [32.508 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [1.952 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [2.157 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [2.818 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [1.788 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [368.311 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [3.107 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [1.856 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [1.973 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [2.14 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [2.022 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [1.781 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [1.967 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [411.338 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [3.252 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [1.769 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [1.746 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [4.04 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [1.758 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [1.81 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [1.817 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [1.686 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [317.336 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [3.084 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [3.624 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [3.147 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [1.95 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [2.16 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [1.987 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [1.9 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [335.572 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [1.835 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [1.707 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [1.896 ms]
PROCESSING TIME [3.084 ms]
```

My client code is using netty 5.0.0.Alpha2 and my server is using netty 4.0.30.Final,

My client code is same as,

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/echo/EchoClient.java
https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/echo/EchoClientHandler.java

My server code is,

```
    final EventLoopGroup parentGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(5);
    final EventLoopGroup childGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try
    {
        final ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(parentGroup, childGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100).handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(final SocketChannel ch) throws Exception
                    {
                        final ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                        if (sslCtx != null)
                        {
                            p.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
                        }
                        NettyServer.this.framer = (Framer) Class.forName(NettyServer.this.manifest.getFramingConfig()).newInstance();
                        NettyServer.this.headerClass = Class.forName(NettyServer.this.manifest.getHeaderConfig());

                        final NettyServerHandler nettyServerHandler = new NettyServerHandler(NettyServer.this.moduleName, NettyServer.this.framer, NettyServer.this.headerClass,
                                NettyServer.this.requestProcessor.clone());
                        p.addLast(nettyServerHandler);
                    }
                });

        // Start the server.
        final ChannelFuture f = b.bind(this.port).sync();

        // Wait until the server socket is closed.
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    }
    finally
    {
        // Shut down all event loops to terminate all threads.
        parentGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        childGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
```

Comment: what is your pipeline and bootstrap configuration ?

Comment: any insight on how you implemented the client/server?